# php string will break if string have php opening tag

Tags: php

My code is below

```
<?php echo '6p]<?mSKPQ'; ?>
```

Above code showing result like below

```
6p]
```

But I need like below

```
6p]<?mSKPQ
```

So what should I do for avoid to break string if string have php opening tag.

Comment: add backslash before special characters or use double quotes

Comment: Yes I also tried double quote but it's not working

Comment: Try this: `<?php echo '6p]\<?mSKPQ'; ?>`

Comment: Now result showing 6p]\ with your code

Comment: check My Answer. @chandanjoshi

Comment: Yes I check your answer @TarangP thanks for help brother and explain

Comment: That's not because it's a _"php opening tag"_ but rather that `<` is a HTML element opening tag. If you just write `something<else` directly in an empty HTML file, you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo htmlspecialchars('6p]<?mSKPQ');
```

Comment: that changes result `6p]&lt;?mSKPQ`

Answer (score 2):

Live Example.
https://eval.in/924127

And Before Asking this type of question please read [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Hi but when I use double quote in string then it's not working.

Comment: instead of checking on online widgets check on your local machine.